# lables for plots of multiple y value for one x value

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, label, legend

I am plotting several y values for one x value at a time using this method:

```
x = [0.3, 0.1, 0.4, 0.65, 0.85, 0.9, 0.125]
y = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
plt.figure()
for xe, ye in zip(x, y):
    plt.scatter([xe] * len(ye), ye)
```

and i obtain:

[image]

However, I want to label each plot I obtain but i can't figure out how. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Create a list containing the labels as strings:

```
labels = ["label1", "label2", ...]
```

and then rewrite the for loop to

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    plt.scatter(x[i]*len(y), y[i], label=labels[i])
```

Comment: if i do this then i get an error that x and y are not the same size

Comment: I get that error when running your code too. Note that `ye` can't be called by `len()` as it is not a list, but an element of the list.

Comment: yes actually the error in the code i posted was because y and x had different lengths, however i fixed it